# Outlook add-in with VS 2013 Community Edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, outlook-addin

I have VS 2013 Community Edition and I want to develop Outlook add-in.

In the "New Project" window, I don't see anything about Outlook or Office add-in (in Installed or Online Templates).

Where can I found the missing Templates (maybe in vsix format) ?

Comment: Get VS 2013 Ultimate trial version

Comment: @JesseJames: No need to. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the [Visual Studio Tools for Office 2013](http://aka.ms/officedevtoolsforvs2013). That will include the templates too. VSTO is compatible with the Community Edition, since that is basically just the Profession Edition with some additional licensing.

From the [Visual Studio site](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs):

> Q: How does Visual Studio Community 2013 compare to other Visual Studio editions? 
>   A: Visual Studio Community 2013 **includes all the great functionality of Visual Studio Professional 2013**, designed and optimized for individual developers, students, open source contributors, and small teams.

Comment: No tks, it's perfect !